# Beat position:fixed stacking context of a parent element

Tags: html, css

In the following example, how do I get the #icon to appear below the #dropdown?

[image]

#container's `position: fixed` seems to be causing it to create a new stacking context for its children. Using any other `position` value fixes it, but that is not an option.

- `#icon` must have `position: absolute`
- `#container` must have `position: fixed`
- `#dropdown` must remain a child of `#container`
- `#dropdown` must have `position: absolute`

Looking for a CSS only solution. [Example playground here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Wyza7HFyiC).

Comment: Any HTML and CSS? Please [edit] to provide a [mcve]. Images are acceptable only if they provide more context to a specific problem in the code.

Comment: Under the dropdown [like this?](https://play.tailwindcss.com/5x12cIJiWU)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan link to code is provided in the description

Comment: @SinisaM No. That's just moving #icon below #dropdown. I meant underneath, so that it is hidden by #dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `#icon`'s parent element so it is in the same stacking context as `#dropdown`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="relative p-10">
  <div id="container" class="fixed w-[700px] rounded-lg border border-neutral-200 bg-white p-6">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
      <div class="h-3.5 w-full max-w-[130px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 text-xl font-bold leading-none !text-transparent text-slate-800">Open tasks</div>
      <div class="relative mt-2">
        <button class="relative h-9 w-full cursor-default rounded-md bg-white py-1.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-left text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6" id="headlessui-listbox-button-:Rd5jdm:" type="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" data-headlessui-state="open" aria-controls="headlessui-listbox-options-:ru:">
          <span class="flex items-center"><div class="h-[12px] min-w-[64px] cursor-pointer rounded-full bg-gray-200 leading-none !text-transparent">Sorting by most recent</div></span
          ><span class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 ml-3 flex items-center pr-2"
            ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.23 7.21a.75.75 0 011.06.02L10 11.168l3.71-3.938a.75.75 0 111.08 1.04l-4.25 4.5a.75.75 0 01-1.08 0l-4.25-4.5a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg
          ></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="dropdown" class="absolute z-10 mt-1 max-h-56 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm" aria-labelledby="headlessui-listbox-button-:Rd5jdm:" aria-orientation="vertical" id="headlessui-listbox-options-:ru:" role="listbox" tabindex="0" data-headlessui-state="open" aria-activedescendant="headlessui-listbox-option-:r12:">
          <li class="relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-gray-900" id="headlessui-listbox-option-:rv:" role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="true" data-headlessui-state="selected">
            <div class="flex items-center"><div class="h-[12px] w-[64px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 leading-none !text-transparent"></div></div>
            <span class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4 text-gray-200"
              ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" class="h-5 w-5"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.704 4.153a.75.75 0 01.143 1.052l-8 10.5a.75.75 0 01-1.127.075l-4.5-4.5a.75.75 0 011.06-1.06l3.894 3.893 7.48-9.817a.75.75 0 011.05-.143z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg
            ></span>
          </li>
          <li class="relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-gray-900" id="headlessui-listbox-option-:r10:" role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" data-headlessui-state="">
            <div class="flex items-center"><div class="h-[12px] w-[64px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 leading-none !text-transparent"></div></div>
          </li>
          <li class="relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-gray-900" id="headlessui-listbox-option-:r11:" role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" data-headlessui-state="">
            <div class="flex items-center"><div class="h-[12px] w-[64px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 leading-none !text-transparent"></div></div>
          </li>
          <li class="relative cursor-default select-none bg-green-300 py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-white" id="headlessui-listbox-option-:r12:" role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" data-headlessui-state="active">
            <div class="flex items-center"><div class="h-[12px] w-[64px] rounded-full bg-green-100 leading-none !text-transparent"></div></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-6 flex flex-col gap-4">
      <div class="flex h-9 items-center gap-4 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 px-4">
        <div class="h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-green-300 leading-none !text-transparent"></div>
        <div class="h-3 w-[300px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 text-sm leading-none !text-transparent text-slate-800">Follow-up call with John Smith</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex h-9 items-center gap-4 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 px-4">
        <div class="h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-gray-200 leading-none !text-transparent"></div>
        <div
          class="h-3 w-[630px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 text-sm leading-none !text-transparent text-slate-800"
          style="
    width: 500px;
"
        >
          Send product brochure to Sarah Lee
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex h-9 items-center gap-4 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 px-4">
        <div class="h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-red-300 leading-none !text-transparent"></div>
        <div class="h-3 w-[495px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 text-sm leading-none !text-transparent text-slate-800">Presentation to Global Industries Inc.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex h-9 items-center gap-4 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 px-4">
        <div class="h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-green-300 leading-none !text-transparent"></div>
        <div class="h-3 w-[300px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 text-sm leading-none !text-transparent text-slate-800">Follow-up with Emily Chen</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex h-9 items-center gap-4 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 px-4">
        <div class="h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-gray-200 leading-none !text-transparent"></div>
        <div class="h-3 w-[421px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 text-sm leading-none !text-transparent text-slate-800">Research Innovative Solutions Co.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex h-9 items-center gap-4 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 px-4">
        <div class="h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-green-300 leading-none !text-transparent"></div>
        <div class="h-3 w-[497px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 text-sm leading-none !text-transparent text-slate-800">Update contact information for Olivia Davis</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-6 flex justify-end">
      <div class="hover:darken-hover active:darken-active flex h-[36px] min-w-[160px] cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-full border border-solid border-gray-200 bg-white uppercase"><div class="h-3.5 min-w-[40px] rounded-full bg-gray-200 text-xs font-medium leading-none !text-transparent text-slate-500">Create new task</div></div>
    </div>
    <div color="#0098ff" class="absolute left-[550px] top-[150px] w-10">
      <span id="icon" data-cy="info-icon" data-usln="editor-currenttooltip-icon" aria-hidden="false"
        ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M17.313 12V9.312h-2.625V12h2.625zm0 10.688v-8h-2.625v8h2.625zM16 2.688c7.375 0 13.313 5.938 13.313 13.313S23.375 29.314 16 29.314 2.687 23.376 2.687 16.001 8.625 2.688 16 2.688z"></path></svg
      ></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close, but in this situation, #icon appears underneath #container. It should still be visible if #dropdown is closed.

Comment: That seems unfair - that stipulation was not specified in the original question.

Comment: Solutioned updated with respect to the extra stipulation.

Comment: Yea I figured that was the only way, so there is no pure CSS solution? Only to move the icon. Thanks for your help